# Capturing Daily Values from One Sheet to Another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet in which data is entered daily on worksheet #1 and a bunch of calculations are made on this worksheet. The values from these calculations are brought to worksheet #2 in chronological order  based on the DATE that the data is entered. The next day, the previous day's data is cleared, a new DATE is entered and new data is entered (and new calcs). The COPY function will not allow the previous day’s data to stay in worksheet #2.

Is there a function that will capture the data as values on worksheet #2 ?

Comment: Scripting is a good idea here, specifically to automate routine tasks. It seem that you should be making some Range.getValues() and Range.setValues(). Go on and script it, come back here on a more specific problem.

Comment: i have column E with  stocks values of items  listed in column A.column F has date ,i want to save stock values with each date in sheet#2, so that stock value for particular date is known.stock value changes every day and so as date.